# python, iterate on subprocess.Popen() stdout/stderr

Tags: python, subprocess

There are a lot of similar posts, but I didn't find answer.

On Gnu/Linux, with `Python` and `subprocess` module, I use the following code to iterate over the
stdout/sdterr of a command launched with subprocess:

```
class Shell:
    """ 
    run a command and iterate over the stdout/stderr lines
    """

    def __init__(self):

        pass

    def __call__(self,args,cwd='./'):

        p = subprocess.Popen(args,
                cwd=cwd, 
                stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,
                )

        while True:

            line = p.stdout.readline()
            self.code = p.poll()

            if line == '':
                if self.code != None:
                    break
                else:
                    continue

            yield line

#example of use
args = ["./foo"]
shell = Shell()
for line in shell(args):
     #do something with line
     print line,
```

This works fine... except if the command executed is `python`, for example `args = ['python','foo.py'], in which case the output is not flushed but printed only when the command is finished.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print).

You need to run the python subprocess with the -u option:

> -u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.  On  sys‐
>                 tems where it matters, also put stdin, stdout and stderr in binary
>                 mode.  Note that there  is  internal  buffering  in  xreadlines(),
>                 readlines()  and  file-object  iterators ("for line in sys.stdin")
>                 which is not influenced by this option.  To work around this,  you
>                 will want to use "sys.stdin.readline()" inside a "while 1:" loop.

Or, if you have control over the python sub-process script you can use sys.stdout.flush() to flush the output every time you print.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: thank! I was so focus on the Shell class, that I forgott to flush the output in the python sub-process script. thanks again